# ajax call inside another ajax call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a method in `Test.vue` component. I imported it to my `main.js` and i can call its methods like that:`this.$refs.test.testMethod()`.

I have a method `ajaxMethod()` in `Test.vue` which looks like this:

```
 function ajaxMethod(){
   this.$http.post(url).then(function(res){ return "hi from test"})
 }
```

Now i make an ajax call from my main method (which is in `main.js`) like that:

```
this.$http.post(url).then(function(response){
let a = this.$refs.test.ajaxMethod()
console.log(a) //a is undefined
})"
```

I tried to set variable's value in Test.vue and then read it from main.js like that:

```
//in Test.vue
data:{
  variable:""
}
methods:{
function ajaxMethod(){
   this.$http.post(url).then(function(res){ 
      this.variable="hi from test"
   })
}
}

//in main.js
this.$http.post(url).then(function(response){
   this.$refs.test.ajaxMethod()
    console.log(this.$refs.test.variable) //when i call that function first time result is empty string and when i call it second time result is 'hi from test'
})"
```

I expect `ajaxMethod()` to return 'hi from test' not `undefined`

**EDIT**

I could resolve it by using this workaround:

```
 a.then(function(val){console.log(val)})
```

as i understand i used value in `promise`, is that ok or is there another "proper" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your ajaxMethod. And you should not couple your components like this. Be carefull about synchronous and asynchronous code blocks. The post method return a promise not the value. You get the value in the callback function.

```
function ajaxMethod(){
   return this.$http.post(url);
}
```

you need to return the promise

```
this.$refs.test.ajaxMethod().then(function(res){
    console.log(res)
})
```

and then get the value. I don't know the exact case but I think you should use events to send data from child to parent instead of this way.

Edit for your edit: 
As I said you should use events instead of this way.